# Remove separator line of single row in Eureka

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, eureka-forms

**How can I remove a separator line of a single row in a Eureka Form?**

I would like to remove the last line in the tableview, the one underneath the description row. When I looked around for a solution for this problem with a regular tableview, the most popular solution is to push the separator line of a specific cell out of the screen by setting a large separator inset. Like this:

```
form.last! <<< TextAreaRow("description row") {
    $0.placeholder = "Description of the issue"
    $0.textAreaHeight = .dynamic(initialTextViewHeight: 44)
}.cellSetup{ cell, row in
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 2000, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}.onChange{ [weak self] in
    self?.issueMessage = $0.value ?? ""
}
```

I'm calling this on `viewDidLoad`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I'm new to Eureka.

[image: Screenshot of Eureka form]

Comment: have you tried to set cell's separator style ?? self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone

Comment: Yes. It's a property on the tableview. It removes seperator lines on all cells, that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
form.last! <<< TextAreaRow("description row") {
            $0.placeholder = "Description of the issue"
            $0.textAreaHeight = .dynamic(initialTextViewHeight: 44)
        }.cellSetup{ (cell, row) in
            if(row != 3) {
                cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 2000, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            }
        }.onChange{ [weak self] in
            self?.issueMessage = $0.value ?? ""
        }
```

I added check (row != 3) by considering you have 4 rows only and index of 4th will be 3 as it starts with 0.

Comment: How does that change anything?

Comment: You want remove line for 4th item, means row will be 3. So we can keep change if(row != 3) then set separatorInset otherwise not. So it will show separator for 0,1,2 cells and not for 3

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4, 5

in `layoutSubview`

```swift
public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        for view in self.subviews where view != self.contentView {
            if NSStringFromClass(type(of: view)).contains("_UITableViewCellSeparatorView")
                view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
```