# How to hide UITableView section separator using Eureka

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, eureka-forms

I'm using the [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) framework for styling the grouped UITableView, and I want to hide the thin separator that appears between the Section header and the first cell of the section (but leave the separator in the first section). The code below hides separator correctly but only when the cell appears on the screen. When I open the controller and see the TableView, the separator is there and I need to scroll the cell off the screen and scroll it back to make it work. Is there any way to hide the separator? On the screenshot below the *Height* cell has hidden separator (what Im trying to achieve) and *Current weight* cell still presents the separator. Is there any way to hide the separator right away?

[image: The Height cell has hidden separator and Current weight cell still presents the separator]

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
    
    if let divider = cell.subviews.first(where: { $0.frame.minY == 0 && $0 !== cell.contentView }) {
        divider.isHidden = indexPath.section != 0 && indexPath.row == 0 ? true : false
    }
    
    cell.setNeedsDisplay()
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I added solution to this, check it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/66432103/2132379

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload your table view in viewDidLoad ow viewWillAppear

Comment: It doesn't work when I reload table in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, but it does when I reload it in viewDidAppear. But still, separators are visible for a moment

Comment: Try to remove separator lines in table view and just add your own separators if you need it

Comment: I suppose that's the only way to do it. I thought that there's some fast and elegant way of doing it. It's quite odd that the separators aren't removed when the table is loaded

Comment: Its quite odd, but it give you more space to customize your cell